# Jagged to Multidimensional Array

Tags: c#, linq

A co-worker and I are currently engaged in a series of coding challenges.

However we like to make things slightly more interesting and golf our answers down (Yes I know, C# is not the greatest golfing language)

Our most recent one involved rotating a cube (int[,]). So eventually we came up with a bet, if I can get this in one line he buys me lunch and vice versa.

After many backspaces and words my mother would hate to hear me say, I finally got it, or so I thought.

I ended up with int[][].

And as far as I can see there is no easy way to convert this to int[,].
so I'm asking if it is actually possible within one line.

> EDIT 1

I would post my source code, but then my co-worker could find it and I could lose a free lunch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try learning javascript (the one I'm using is a very common pattern in libraries).

```
int[][] jagged = new[] { new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }, new[] { 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 } };

int[,] array = ((Func<int[][], int[,]>)(x =>
{
    int[,] temp = new int[x.Length, x.Length != 0 ? x[0].Length : 0];
    for (int i = 0; i < x.Length; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < x[0].Length; j++)
        {
            temp[i, j] = x[i][j];
        }
    }

    return temp;
}))(jagged);
```

The `int[,] array =` can be made a single line just removing the end of lines. I declare an anonymous method and then call it (see the `(jagged)`? It is me calling the anonymous method).

**single statement version**

```
int[,] array = jagged.Length == 0 ? 
    new int[0,0] : 
    jagged.SelectMany(x => x)
        .Select((x, ix) => new
        {
            i = ix / jagged[0].Length,
            y = ix % jagged[0].Length,
            val = x
        })
        .Aggregate(new int[jagged.Length, jagged[0].Length], (md, x) => (md[x.i, x.y] = x.val) == x.val ? md : null);
```

Here I'm using the `Aggregate()` method. The `TSeed` is the destination multi-dimensional array. Note the `(md[x.i, x.y] = x.val) == x.val ? md : null`: I need to assign the `md[x.i, x.y] = x.val` BUT I need to return `md` (because `Aggregate` requires the function to work this way). I make an useless check`(md[x.i, x.y] = x.val) == x.val` and use the ternary operator to return `md`.

Note that I'm closing a variable (`jagged`), but the closure could be removed (I think).... Mmmmh seems to be complex.

Comment: Technically I could make any C# program a one-liner  by just pressing delete at the end of every line.

Tried learning JS, didn't grab me.

Comment: @Darkestlyrics yes... but still this is a single assignment statement... It is less playing with words. There is no meaningful difference between this code and doing `var enu = coll.Select(y => { return y; })`.

Comment: fair enough, lemme play around with this instead of linq.

Comment: @Darkestlyrics The problem here is that you defined the bet in terms of lines... You should have defined the bet in term of statesments.

Comment: fair enough, but we like to make things difficult for ourselves. worst case I lose a lunch but I learn something new.  Breaks up the monotony of the standard questions and really forces us to explore the capabilites of the language.

Comment: @Darkestlyrics But as you said, in the "one line program" you can put any C# program that doesn't use preprocessor directives (`#something`), so your problem was already automatically solvable.

Comment: Yeah but that just feels like cheating.

The Func works but still feels like it's cheating, will mark this this at the accepted answer unless anyone manages to tame the beast that is Linq.

Comment: @Darkestlyrics Non-cheating version using Aggregate.

Answer (score 7):

You'll need at least two lines, one for declaring your result array and one for the actual copying of the data.

You could first flatten your array of array to a single array, and the use [`Buffer.BlockCopy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.buffer.blockcopy(v=vs.110).aspx) to copy all data to the result array.

Here's an example:

```
var source = new int[][] {
    new int[4]{1,2,3,4},
    new int[4]{5,6,7,8},
    new int[4]{1,3,2,1},
    new int[4]{5,4,3,2}
};

var expected = new int[4,4] {
    {1,2,3,4},
    {5,6,7,8},
    {1,3,2,1},
    {5,4,3,2}
};

var result = new int[4, 4];
// count = source.Length * source[0].Length * sizeof(int) = 64, since BlockCopy is byte based
// to be dynamically you could also use System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(source[0][0]) instead of sizeof(int)
Buffer.BlockCopy(source.SelectMany(r => r).ToArray(), 0, result, 0, 64);

result.Dump("result");
expected.Dump("expected");
```

Result:

[image]

If you insist of being fancy: you could call `BlockCopy` dynamically with an delegate to have that delegate return `Object` so you can use it for an assignment of an anonymous class, which is apparently in the spirit of your rules, and wrap everything into a collection so you end with a single line monster like this:

```
var result = new[]{ new int[4, 4] }.Select(x => new { r = x, tmp = Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action<Array, int, Array, int, int>), typeof(Buffer).GetMethod("BlockCopy")).DynamicInvoke(new Object[]{source.SelectMany(r => r).ToArray(), 0, x, 0, 64})}).First().r;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are allowed to use `Func<>` and lambda you can certainly do it and make a generic extension to transform the object you are calling it on.

```
/// <typeparam name="T">Output type</typeparam>
/// <typeparam name="U">Calling type</typeparam>
/// <param name="obj">object to pipe</param>
/// <param name="func">blackbox function</param>
/// <returns>whatever</returns>
public static T ForThis<T,U> (this U obj, Func<U,T> func)
{
    return func(obj);
}
```

With this you should be able to transform int[,] to int[][] by doing something like:

```
int[][] output = input.ForThis<int[][], int[,]>((obj) =>
{
    // transform obj == input of type int[,] into int[][]
    throw new NotImplementedException();
});
```

Although I admit that this solution really feels like cheating because you are just sort of wrapping the multiline transformation into a lambda.

Comment: Yeah we looked at this and both agreed this is sort of cheating. But thanks for the answer.